# What can cause a MacBook Pro mid 2015 sound output to fade rapidly to silence?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio

Today when i am using my mbp 2015 retina , sound went off suddenly.

Internal speaker or headphones are silent. I can only get sound from hdmi output.

- Sound settings seem ok to me.
- Some unspecified Diagnostic shows no problems.
- No red lights in headphone jack.

  I have reset the nvram and smc. With headphones, 8 hear sound just for a second but that fades out very quickly. I am running OS X mojave and don’t know how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

The amplifier to make sound is the likely cause of failure. Since that’s on the logic board, a free warranty swap or a flat rate repair for $300 or so are the likely costs to fix this properly.

Have you tested installing a new OS on an external drive or wiping and reinstalling in case it’s software? That’s worth doing so you have a backup or confidence you need a repair as well.

Comment: I have reinstalled os but no joy. Right now i started backing up to  timemachine (will take about 8 hours) for wiping drive and make a clean install. There is not much Apple support here in Turkey, they just replace everyting and costs almost a new macbook.

Comment: After everything i tried, i found a service to repair logic board. as @bmike mentioned, its logic board problem, caused by earlier liquid damage. Thanks for the answer. Saved me a lot of time.